# In flutter app development, I'm trying to retrieve list using provider but "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." exception is throwing

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating one fultter mobile app and in that I'm retrieving data from firestore database and storing it into one list, then i'm trying to retrieve that list to display on one page using provider. but list is showing empty while i use to display it.On another page i'm doing same to retrieve that list and list got successfully retrieved. Can someone please tell me where i'm getting wrong?`

---

### Error i'm getting:

I/flutter (14313): 0.0
Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

---

### file where i'm retrieving data from firestore and storing it into list:

```
    class Cart with ChangeNotifier{
  List<CartItem> _items = [];
  void createList() async {
    _items.clear();
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("cart")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((value) => value.documents.forEach((element) {
              _items.add(CartItem(
                  prodid: element.data["productId"],
                  shopId: element.data["shopId"],
                  price: element.data["price"],
                  name: element.data["name"],
                  qty: element.data["qty"],
                  type: element.data["type"],
                  category: element.data["category"],
                  weight: element.data["weight"]));
            }))
        .then((_) {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
  List<CartItem> get items {
    return _items;
  }
  int get itemsCount {
    return _items == null ? 0 : _items.length;
  }
  double get totalAmount{
    double total1 = 0;``
    _items.forEach((cartItem) {
      print(cartItem.price);
      print(cartItem.qty);
      total1 = total1 + cartItem.price * cartItem.qty;
    });
    notifyListeners();
    return total1;
  }
```

---

### file where i'm trying top retrieve above retrieved list from firestore

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:groceryappstask/models/carttem.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Eigth_page.dart';

class seventhpage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    List<CartItem> cartProd = cart.items;
    print("-----------------------------------------------");
    print("-----------------------------------------------");
    print("-----------------------------------------------");
    print("-----------------------------------------------");
    print("-------------------seventh page----------------------------");

    print(cartProd.length);
    print(Provider.of<Cart>(context).totalAmount);
   // cart.items.forEach((element) {print(element.name);});

    return Provider<Cart>(
      create: (context) => Cart(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Total = Rs.',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Consumer<Cart>(
                                builder: (context, cart, ch) {
                                  double total =
                                      Provider.of<Cart>(context).totalAmount;
                                  // print(total);
                                  //   print("total item");
                                  //   print(Provider.of<Cart>(context).itemsCount);
                                  return Text(
                                    Provider.of<Cart>(context)
                                        .totalAmount
                                        .toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.orange[800],
                            child: Text(
                              'Proceed to Pay',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.sort,
                            size: 35,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.format_line_spacing,
                            size: 35,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Consumer<Cart>(
              builder: (context, cart, ch) => Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      itemCount: cartProd.length,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'images/atta.png',
                                        height: 55,
                                        width: 55,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 3,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        cartProd[index].name,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 17,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        cartProd[index].weight.toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

That's actually a simple error, the problem is in this line: `Provider.of<Cart>(context).totalAmount`

When you call this, you have a `notifyListeners()` in the end of your `totalAmount` function, and since you didn't specify the listen value, it is true by default and the page is going to rebuild as soon as it reaches the `notifyListeners()`, and then it will reach that line again and rebuilds again and again....

To fix that, you should specify that you're not listening to incoming changes, to do so, you specify the listen value to false, as following:

`Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).totalAmount`

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply but that's not issue. in seventhpage class where i'm printing message as "---seventh page---" ,just below that i'm trying to fetch list using provider. that list is getting empty.And in future i want to listen value so i can't assign it as false.